# CTDB failover and samba/openldap authentication fails

Tags: samba, centos7, openldap

I'm trying to setup a HA storage with gluster. Share it with Samba so I can access it on Windows clients. CTDB for HA connection to the clients and OpenLDAP for user authentication. It's a virtual test setup which we maybe want to use for the company. All the VMs can ping eachother. I'm using CentOS 7.

- Gluster node 1: 192.168.2.210
- Gluster node 2: 192.168.2.211
- LDAP server: 192.168.2.95
- Windows client: 192.168.2.100 (Windows 10)

I got my gluster volume working (distributed replicated). I can't get CTDB failover and samba/openldap authentication to work. The ctdb config file, public_addresses and nodes files are located on my gluster volume and linked(symbolic) to /etc/sysconfig/ctdb, /etc/ctdb/public_addresses and /etc/ctdb/nodes.

/etc/sysconfig/ctdb > /gluster/lock/ctdb

```
CTDB_RECOVERY_LOCK=/gluster/lock/.CTDB-lockfile
CTDB_NODES=/etc/ctdb/nodes
CTDB_PUBLIC_ADDRESSES=/etc/ctdb/public_addresses
CTDB_MANAGES_SAMBA=yes
```

public_addessses > /gluster/lock/public_addresses

```
192.168.2.215/24 ens33
```

/etc/ctdb/nodes > /gluster/lock/nodes

```
192.168.2.210
192.168.2.211
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
idmap backend = tdb2
clustering = yes

[gluster-data]
vfs object = glusterfs
glusterfs:volume = data
glusterfs:logfile = /var/log/samba/glusterfs-data.%M.log
glusterfs:loglevel = 7
path = /gluster/share
read only = no
create mask = 0770
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
```

So first of all my CTDB is working the opposite way. I can only ping the floating IP-address when both nodes are online. 'ctdb status' says both nodes are OK and 'ctdb ip' shows the floating IP-address. When I try to access the volume on my Windows client I keep getting the error: 'The specified network password is not correct'. I did run smbpasswd -a 'testuser' on both nodes. Even root won't authenticate.
So then I thought I could try OpenLDAP for user authentication. I changed the samba settings to:

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://192.168.2.95
idmap backend = ldap:ldap://192.168.2.95
ldap suffix = dc=domain,dc=com
ldap admin dn = cn=ldapadm,dc=domain,dc=com
clustering = yes

[gluster-data]
vfs object = glusterfs
glusterfs:volume = data
glusterfs:logfile = /var/log/samba/glusterfs-data.%M.log
glusterfs:loglevel = 7
path = /gluster/share
read only = no
create mask = 0770
valid users = @Users
force group = Users
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
```

With these settings I can't even ping the floating CTDB IP-address and ctdb status says the nodes are UNHEALTY. I also ran smbpasswd -W 'ldapadm password'. Using a CentOS client I can log in to the OpenLDAP user.

I'm fairly new to all this and english isn't my native language so sorry for any mistakes. I hope someone can help me and can provide more information if I didn't give all that's needed.